# Prove sum of $k^2$ using $k^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, telescopic-series

So the title may be a little bit vague, but I am quite stuck with the following problem.
Asked is to first prove that $(k + 1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k + 1$. This is not the problem however. The question now asks to prove that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$ using the fact that $(k + 1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k + 1$. I have no idea however to start working on this. Anyone have any idea? Does this have anything to do with telescopic series?

Comment: The way I like for this kind of problem is to have $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3) - (k-1)k(k+1)(k+2) = \sum_{k=1}^n 4k(k+1)(k+2) = n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ which leads us to $\sum_{k=1}^n (k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4}$, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^n (k^3) = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4} - 3 \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - 2\sum_{k=1}^n k$, which use the telescopic sum directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: take the sum for $k=1$ to $n$ of both sides of the equation $(k+1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k + 1$.

Comment: so you get this equation? $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}((k + 1)^3 - k^3) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (3k^2 + 3k + 1) $$

Comment: Yes. Now evaluate as much as you can.

Comment: I tried that but then I come out to this equation, where all terms would cancel each other out: $$ 3(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}k) + n = 3(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}k) + n $$

Comment: Don't do that to the left hand side. You've already noted that it's a telescoping sum.

Comment: so just evaluate the right side then? I don't see how that helps.

Comment: Oh now I see how this is done :)

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Patrick’s hint, $$\sum_{k=1}^n(3k^2+3k+1) \\ =3\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+3\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n 1 \\ =3S +3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n$$ This equals the telescoping sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n[(k+1)^3-k^3]=(n+1)^3-1=n^3+3n^2+3n $$

Rearranging the terms gives the result $$S=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Comment: I don't see how the telescoping sum is derived from the formula $ 3S + 3\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n $

Comment: @Matthias K. It’s not. I’m just using the fact that   $$\sum_{k=1}^n (3k^2+3k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^n [(k+1)^3-k^3] $$

Comment: I get it now :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Matthias K. No worries!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
This is a model  for the general method to find a recursive relation to calculate
$$S_r(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^r$$
Generalising your giving relation with the binomial formula, you get
$$(k+1)^{r+1}-k^{r+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{r+1}\binom{r+1}i k^{r+1-i}$$
and adding these relations, taking into account the telescoping sum in the left hand side, there results the relation
$$\sum_{i=1}^r\binom{r+1}i S_i(n)=(n+1)^{r+1}-(n+1).$$